# "Нужен" и "нужно" - разные части речи? И какие именно?

Tags: грамотная-речь, части

Контекст такой: "Какие документы нужны для..." и "Какие документы нужно подготовить для..."

Answer (score 3):

**Какие документы нужны для...**

Двусоставное предложение, ***нужны*** ― именная часть сказуемого  выражена кратким прилагательным.

**Какие документы нужно подготовить для...**

Односоставное безличное предложение, ***нужно*** ―  именная часть сказуемого выражена предикативным наречием (словом категории состояния) с модальным значением.

Comment: А на другом ресурсе мне вот что написали: 
"Вам объяснили в корне неправильно. Предикатив "нужно" - это связка (да, модального характера) в составном глагольном сказуемом, а никак не именная часть составного именного сказуемого.

И наречием называть его нехорошо. Можно ещё сказать "предикатив наречного типа", чтобы указать на омонимию с наречием, но это совершенно разные части речи:
"Он легко (наречие) вскочил на ноги. На душе (было) необыкновенно легко (предикатив)".

Comment: Продолжаю:
Наречие - это спецификация имени или глагола, а не автономная характеристика состояния. (Вскочил как? Легко.) И у него нет аналитических форм времени."

Comment: Re: "Предикатив "нужно" - это связка (да, модального характера) в составном глагольном сказуемом". Во-первых, не связка, во-вторых, не в глагольном. "Это было нужно" - здесь составное именное сказуемое со связкой было.