# Какой вид предложения и сказуемого: мне нужно поговорить

Tags: грамматика, сказуемые

**Диалог:**

*— Мне нужно...*

*— Что тебе нужно?*

*— Мне **нужно поговорить**.*

Тема предикативного наречия ***"нужно"*** обсуждалась **[здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/437777/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8-%D0%98-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE/437781?noredirect=1#comment516272_437781),** мнения были разные.